# Unable to grab the ID generated by firebase when converting to array

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, axios

I'm using CRA & axios to pull down some JSON as an object from firebase, then convert it into an array for it to be rendered.

This appears to be successful, and I can log the array, however I appear to be unable to grab the ID generated by firebase (e.g. -M9SUPLwY3KgRNmOLS17)

Which I require in order to be able to navigate to the correct tour page.

Expected outcome: 
/tours/-M9SUPLwY3KgRNmOLS17/tour

Current outcome:
/tours/undefined/tour

**JSX**

```
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('FIREBASEURL/tours.json')
    .then(response => {
      const obj = response.data;
      const resArr = []
        for (let key in obj) {
          resArr.push(obj[key])
        }
      this.tours = resArr
      this.setState({tours: resArr})
    })
  }


  render() {
    const { tours } = this.state
   return (
      <div>
        <div className="tours">
        {tours ? (tours.map(tours => (
           <Link to={`/tours/${tours.id}/tour`} className="trslink">
            <div key={tours.id + Math.random()} className="trsIndiv">
              <h3 className="title">{tours.tour.name}</h3>
              <div className="desc">{tours.tour.description}</div>
              <p className="longdesc">
                <strong>City:</strong> {tours.tour.city}<br/>
                <strong>Duration:</strong> {tours.tour.duration} hrs<br/><br/>
              </p>

            </div>
          </Link>
          ))
        ) : (
        <div></div>
        )}
        </div>
      </div>
      )
  }
```

**JSON example**

```
{
 "-GHJSDAGFAD1" : {
   "tour" : {
     "city" : "London, England",
     "description" : "Drink to your hearts content.",
     "duration" : 5,
     "full_description" : "Long Description TBC",
     "name" : "The Fighting Lion",
     "rating" : 4
   }
 },
 "-QEWURYK2" : {
   "tour" : {
     "city" : "London, England",
     "description" : "Top Pub!",
     "duration" : 2,
     "full_description" : "Long Description TBC",
     "name" : "The Frisky Goose",
     "rating" : 3.5
   }
 }
}
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, has anyone any advice? Thanks,

Comment: first, change tours to tour in map callback function ` tours ? (tours.map(`tour` =>) ` 
You are adding keys in the array, or you have an array of keys, but you are accessing id on the string which will give you undefined

Comment: Unfortunately this is still returning undefined, and now returning the rest of the items (e.g. city) as undefined too.

Answer (score 0):

The key of a document is the JavaScript object key -- it is not otherwise embedded in the content. I think you probably want something like:

```
  axios.get('FIREBASEURL/tours.json')
    .then(response => {
      const obj = response.data;
      const resArr = []
        for (let key in obj) {
          resArr.push(Object.assign({id: key}, obj[key]))
        }
      this.tours = resArr
      this.setState({tours: resArr})
    })
```

The difference being that `Object.assign` is adding an `id` property to the resulting objects in the array.